# HtmlAgility Xpath Issue

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse with HTMLAgility the following :

```
<span class="button">
<a role="anotherbutton" href="/gofor/15555445554/be?ref=t">Me</a>
</span>
```

with something like this :

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class = 'button']/a[@role = 'anotherbutton']"))
        {
            string att = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
            txt_htmlResults.Text += att.ToString() + "\n";      
        }
```

However I always get null exception... My intention is to get the 15555445554. Can someone assist. Thank you in advance

Comment: Where in your foreach loop does the null exception occur?

Comment: Have you debugged it? Have you verified that `link.Attributes["href"]` actually returns something?

Comment: The issue is in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes it returns null....  The Xpath is incorrect If i put for example //a[@href] I get all the hrefs in page..

Comment: Is it exactly that HTML above you're trying to parse, or is that from a larger document?

Comment: `SelectNodes` does return null if it can't match any nodes to the XPath, but your XPath works for me on the given HTML... Are you certain that the input HTML looks like that?

Answer (score 2):

threw it in a text file on my c drive:

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load("C:\\temp\\stackhtml.html");
    //string link = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='button']//a").OuterHtml;
    string rawLink = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='button']//a").GetAttributeValue("href", "unkown");
    Console.WriteLine("rawLink: " + rawLink);
    string cleanedLink = rawLink.Substring(rawLink.IndexOf("r/")+2,rawLink.IndexOf("/b")-rawLink.IndexOf("r/")-2);
    Console.WriteLine("cleanedLink: " + cleanedLink);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Good one, you can also check the null on document node while loading html into it.

`var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.selectNodes("xpath");

if(nodes !=null && nodes.Any())
{
//write your logic here
//todo: code
}`